# Find all logical drives from a unitmask

Tags: c++, winapi

I have wrote a program to detect usb drive whenever it is inserted. I want to know all the partitions on the usb. If my drive has one partition (example `E:/`), then the program detects successfully. But if the usb drive has two partition (example: `E:`, `F:`) then only first partition `E:` is detected but I do not know how to detect `F:` or other partitions of the usb. On inserting a usb drive, `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` is triggered.

```
case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
            
            if (b->dbcc_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
            {
                
                PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR lpdbh = (PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR)lParam;
                PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME vol = (PDEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME)lParam;
                char drive = FirstDriveFromMask(vol->dbcv_unitmask);                
            }
```

The function FirstDriveFromMask() can detect first encountered partition from mask. How do I detect the other partitions from the usb drive.

```
char FirstDriveFromMask(ULONG unitmask)// (usb has drive e:, f: )unitmask I receive is 48. Output is E
{
    for (char i = 0; i < 26; ++i, unitmask >>= 1)
        if (unitmask & 0x1)
            return i + 'A';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take a closer look at that `FirstDriveFromMask` function. Notice how it returns *immediately* once it finds a match? Perhaps it would be better is you added the drive to a container (e.g. `std::vector<std::string>`) and returned that container once all bits have been iterated over?

Comment: You could refer to the function `DrivesFromMask` in this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62792258/10611792).

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT The sample has all the code I need. Thank you too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following function could be helpful:

```
std::string DrivesFromMask(ULONG unitmask)
{
    char i;
    std::string drv = "";
    for (i = 0; i < 26 && unitmask; ++i)
    {
        if (unitmask & 0x1)
        {
            drv += i + 'A';
        }
        unitmask = unitmask >> 1;
    }
    return drv;
}
```

And then read each drive letter in `std::string`.