# What event does Windows use to detect a drive has been unlocked by bitlocker?

Tags: c++, windows, security, wmi, bitlocker

The scenario is this:

Open two instances of Windows explorer on a computer with a locked drive.

Click on the drive in one of the windows and enter its BitLocker password.

The drive unlocks, and the icon on the second window changes to unlocked as well.

Obviously, Windows has some event it's listening to, to receive this information. What is it?

Comment: Remove the `c++` tag, as there is no mention of programming languages in your post.

Comment: This is better posted at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: might be relevant: [Capture encrypted USB decryption event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62792258/8411406)